# How to merge rows based on <td> class? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm currently trying to make it so that when the JS code does its thing, the rows with common values and common classes will be merged. The code worked, but all of the common rows were merged without taking into account their classes.

Table code:

```
<tbody id="property_dtl_table_body">
   <% dtls.each do |f| %>
   <tr class="<%= payment_paid(f.paid)%>" id="paidrow">
     <td>
       <% if !f.paid %>
       <%= check_box_tag "pin_number[]", f.id, checked= !f.paid? %>
       <%end%>
     </td>

     <td id="pin"><%= f.year %></td>
     <td><%= f.quarter %></td>
     <td align="right" id="price"><%= number_to_currency(f.amount, unit: "", 
precision: 2)%></td>

  </tr>
  <%end%>
</tbody>
```

JS Code:

```
if(!$(this).hasClass('paid')){
    var table = $("#property_dtl_table_body");
    var rows = table.find($("tr"));
    var colsLength = 2;
    var removeLater = new Array();
    for(var i=1; i<colsLength; i++){
        var startIndex = 0;
        var lastIndex = 0;
        var startText = $($(rows[0]).find("td")[i]).text();
        for(var j=1; j<rows.length; j++){
            var cRow =$(rows[j]);
            if(!$(this).hasClass('paid')){
            var cCol = $(cRow.find("td")[i]);
            }
            var currentText = cCol.text();
            if(currentText==startText){
                cCol.css("background","gray");
                console.log(cCol);
                removeLater.push(cCol);
                lastIndex=j;
            }else{
                var spanLength = lastIndex-startIndex;
                if(spanLength>=1){
                    console.log(lastIndex+" - "+startIndex)
                    //console.log($($(rows[startIndex]).find("td")[i]))
                    $($(rows[startIndex]).find("td")
[i]).attr("rowspan",spanLength+1);
                }
                lastIndex = j;
                startIndex = j;
                startText = currentText;
            }

        }
        var spanLength = lastIndex-startIndex;
                if(spanLength>=1){
                    console.log(lastIndex+" - "+startIndex)
                    //console.log($($(rows[startIndex]).find("td")[i]))
                    $($(rows[startIndex]).find("td")
[i]).attr("rowspan",spanLength+1);
                }
        console.log("---");  
      }

      for(var i in removeLater){
          $(removeLater[i]).remove();
      }
}
```

The class in question(#paid) is represented by the green background color as seen here:

Before JS:

[image]

After JS:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean without taking into account their classes? Provide a sample of what the output should look like

Comment: Just added the picture of the expected result to the bottom of question

Comment: `id="pin"` .. `id="price"` — inside a loop?  Oh boy.  This won't end well.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for the following logic:

- Start on the first year td
- Loop through the next year td's until you find a different one and count them
- When you find one, set the first td's rowspan to the number of elements in between
- Remove all those td's that you looped through
- Repeat the process until the end

The same classe restriction only applies to the selector that you use to fetch all the tds.

Example:

```js
function mergeByClass(className){
    let currTd, count = 0;

    $(`tr > .${className}`).each(function(){
        if (!currTd) //if its the first one set it as current
            currTd = $(this);
        else { //if its not
            if ($(this).text() == currTd.text()){ //check if its a repeating one
                count++; //count if it is
                $(this).remove(); //and remove it to properly merge
            }
            else { //if its a different one
                if(count >= 1) //merge if it has 1 or more in between
                    currTd.attr("rowspan", count + 1);

                currTd = $(this); //reset the current one
                count = 0;
            }
        }  
    });

    if (count >= 1) //last element case
        currTd.attr("rowspan", count + 1);
}

$("#merge").on("click", () => mergeByClass("paid"));
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding : 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="merge">Click to merge rows with the same class</button>

<table>


  <tr>
    <td class="paid">2015</td><td>3</td><td>22.97</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="paid">2015</td><td>3</td><td>22.97</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>2016</td><td>3</td><td>22.97</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>2016</td><td>3</td><td>22.97</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>2017</td><td>3</td><td>22.97</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>2017</td><td>3</td><td>22.97</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2017</td><td>3</td><td>22.97</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="paid">2018</td><td>3</td><td>22.97</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="paid">2018</td><td>3</td><td>22.97</td>
  </tr>


</table>
```